# Redirect logged in (authenticated) users to a different frontpage using rules or php code

Tags: 7, uri, redirection

I need to always redirect authenticated users to a different page (to serve as their own frontpage) whenever they try to access the default (anonymous) frontpage. I want to achieve this using rules or through some custom php code in my template.php or settings.php file, NOT by enabling a new module. Thanks.

Added: i created the frontpage using Page Manager (packaged with ctools)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157490/change-the-front-page-value-for-logged-in-users

Comment: I prefer to use the[Front Page module](https://www.drupal.org/project/front)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this using rules bonus pack: https://drupal.org/project/rb

The module to enable is Rules bonus: miscellaneous.

Each panel page now gets an extra tab below other tabs (like Layout, content, Preview) called "Reactions" => "Create a rules event for this variant". After enabling this and saving, Go to your rules events, a new rules event will be added "Rules Bonus: Miscellaneous" => "variant panel is rendered". Select this and save.

Conditions: User has roles (authenticated)

Actions: Page redirect: enter the path to the page e.g. "newpage" (without quotes).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a particular node as your front page:

1. Create a new rule, event: content is viewed
2. Condition: data comparison -> `node:nid` equals to the `nid` of your front page node.
3. Add your conditions for user roles here.
4. Action: page redirect -> enter the path where you want to redirect the users

If you have PHP code module enabled already:

1. Create a new rule, event: content is viewed
2. Condition: execute custom PHP code -> `return drupal_is_front_page();`
3. Add your conditions for user roles here.
4. Action: page redirect -> enter the path where you want to redirect the users

Comment: I am not using a node as my front page, i created the frontpage using page manager.

Comment: Do you have PHP code module enabled already?

Comment: Yes i have PHP module enabled

Comment: Then did you try the second solution I posted? That one works for any type of front pages.

Comment: This didnt work, i have now found a solution. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For me, "Content is viewed" would not work because I use the default front page, which is not a content node.  It probably works if you are using a particular content node as front page.

For me, this worked on Drupal 7.59, Rules 7.x-2.9:

1. Create a new rule, event: Drupal is initializing
2. Condition: Text comparison between data selector [site:current-page:url] and matching text (here I used PHP):

   $front_url = 'https://example.org' . url();

   echo $front_url

The text comparison evaluates to TRUE when Drupal is initalizing the default front page, because my home url is 'https://example.org/drupaldirectory/'

3. Add your conditions for user roles here
4. Action: page redirect: enter the path where you want to redirect users