# Change the front page value for logged in users

Tags: rules

On my site I have two front pages:

- node/31, for anonymous users
- calendar-node-field-journal-date/month, for logged in users

When a users clicks on the front page (which is rendered as `$front_page` in my `page.tpl.php` file), I want them to be taken to the appropriate front page.

However, if a logged in user goes to `node/31` directly (e.g. by not clicking on the front page link) they should still be able to see the node (and not be re-directed).

After researching, I've found Rules is the best way to do this and there are instructions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/93765/redirect-logged-in-authenticated-users-to-a-different-frontpage-using-rules-or).
However, this re-directs logged in users when they visit `node/31`. How can I get the Rule to only run when the user clicks on the `$front_page` link and not on the direct `node/31` link?

I don't want to set it up via my theme, as I am sharing the theme on a multi-site. I also don't really want to install other modules, as I am already using Rules for other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend the [Front Page module](https://www.drupal.org/project/front), not rules:

> The Front Page module allows for customised home pages dependant on
> role. The pages can be of the following types:
>
> Alias (only 2.x branch) - Allows for another Drupal path to be shown
> as the home page without redirecting the user.
>
> Redirect - Allows you to redirect users to a local or remote URL.
>
> Themed - Allows you to enter some static text that will be placed into the content area > of a standard Drupal page. Full - Allows for static content to be displayed
> to the screen as is. This method does not pass through Drupal's
> theming system.

Comment: this has the same problem as rules: If the logged-in user clicks on node/31 directly they will be taken to the front page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: then I would suspect that that is expected behaviour - since Drupal associates the node with the Front page, it assumes your intent was to view the front page when the node is viewed